# SAS two dataset merge if a=b

Tags: merge, sas, dataset

I'm working on SAS to python migration. Can someone explain me what type of join is this or more specifically what's this if a=b doing here.

```
data temp_1;
        merge data_1(in=a)
              data_2(in=b);
        by &by_var.;
        if a = b;
        sum_val = sum(of val_1, val_2);
        run;
```

Comment: Note that the `of` keyword in your SUM() function call is not doing anything.  The OF keyword allows listing of multiple variables in a single argument, but in this case your list is just one variable.  The second variable is not part of the list since it is a separate argument because of the comma.

Comment: Tom, I think `sum(of a, b)` is equal to `sum(of a b)` and `sum(a,b)` and `sum(of a, of b)`.

Comment: Check out the linked question - it explains in some detail what happens, in particular with duplicate records.  This might help your other question, also, as it shows a case where it is _not_ the same thing as a SQL inner join.

Answer (score 1):

The in= data set option specifies a variable that is 1 if the data set contributes to the merge for the specified by-variable and 0 otherwise.

One of the data sets must contribute to the merge, ie. `a` and `b` can not both be zero in the posted code. Therefore `if a = b;` is the same as `if a=1 and b=1;` in this situation.

For better understanding of the merge/in= data set option, run the code below. I create the `_a` and `_b` variables for demonstration only as `a` and `b` are automatically dropped.

```
data one;
input x y;
datalines;
1 1
1 2
2 3
2 4
3 5
3 6
;

data two;
input x;
datalines;
1
3
;

data want;
   merge one(in=a)
         two(in=b);
   by x;
   _a = a;
   _b = b;
   *if a = b;
run;
```